# Gekko SysId - Temprature System Identification

Tags: gekko, system-identification

I am currently working on developing an MPC to optimise the costs of a fridge.
Therefore I need a model of my system. For the modelling of the algorithm, I used GEKKO.
Now I am trying to identify my system using the function "sysid" also found in GEKKO. I just can't understand how does this function work when not given a model of the system. Furthermore, I don't understand the parameters of this function and the meaning of the given outputs. I sow some examples here: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DataSimulation.
This possibility seems promising, I just need a deeper understanding of this function.

I will appreciate any kind of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is additional documentation and examples on the system identification function `sysid`:

- [MIMO (Multiple Input, Multiple Output) System Identification](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ModelIdentification)
- [Arduino TCLab Advanced Control Lab](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/AdvancedTemperatureControl), especially [Lab F](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabF)
- [Nonlinear Control with CSTR](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/NonlinearControl)
- [Gekko Documentation: Model Building Functions (sysid)](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=sysid)

The `sysid` function identifies an ARX model. You can use the ARX model in the `arx` gekko function. Here is some [additional documentation on the ARX model](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/ARXTimeSeries).